# Can I use NextPrime[n] up to n=10^14?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, big-numbers

I would like to perform computations with primes up to $n=10^{14}$. To do so, I would like to go through all primes, from $2$ to $10^{14}$ and perform some calculation on each prime.

I saw that one can use the `NextPrime[]` function to get the smallest prime greater than a given number. However, I find no information about how trustworthy this is, i.e., what I get is not a *pseudo-prime*, but a real, guaranteed prime number. Can I use it up to $10^{14}$ with confidence?

Also, are there any benchmarks on the speed of this function? How long would it take, for instance, on a modern processor to get up to $10^{14}$ with this?

Comment: If you need to the all primes up to $10^14$, a segmented sieve would be the way to go. A rough implementation here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85720/4346

Comment: Currently all primes below $2^{63} - 1$ are calculated deterministically, $10^{18}<2^{63} - 1<10^{19}$. The same concerns `NextPrime` which works there quite well, however. finding e.g. tenth next prime is unsatisfactorily slow (`NextPrime[10^19, 10]`)    See these posts: [What is so special about Prime?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime) and  [Why does iterating Prime in reverse order require much more time?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15799/why-does-iterating-prime-in-reverse-order-require-much-more-time/15862#15862).

Comment: I wouldn't use `NextPrime` for such calculations, much more efficient method would involve simply `PrimePi` and `Prime` instead of `NextPrime`.

Comment: To boost the signal of @GregHurst's comment: if one needs all the primes up to some point, one should always generate all those primes simultaneously—that's significantly faster than doing things one prime at a time.

Answer (score 9):

[`NextPrime`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NextPrime.html) has no problems evaluating for large numbers well above $10^{14}$. I think it's safe to assume these are real prime numbers, for confirmation see the answer by @Roman (+1).

You can benchmark the performance of `NextPrime` and/or your analysis using [`AbsoluteTiming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html) or [`RepeatedTiming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html) for better statistics.

```
RepeatedTiming[
    NextPrime[
        RandomInteger[10^40]
    ]
    ,10
]

(* {0.00116824, 7254438951606515242301428266213800581027} *)
```

So after evaluating random large numbers repeatedly for *10 second*s, we get an average of *1.117ms* per evaluation.

We expect that there will be approximately $n/Log(n)$ prime numbers smaller than $n$ ([Prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)), so assuming *1ms* per iteration, your calculation will take more than *98 years*.

```
With[
    { n = 10^14 },
    UnitConvert[
        Quantity[1., "Millisecond"] * n/Log[n] 
        ,"Years"
    ]
]
(* Quantity[98.36705486320665, "Years"] *)
```

So unless your machine is much faster than mine and you have access to several hundreds of cores, even speeding things up via compilation, I think it may be hard to go over all prime numbers in the range $2$ to $10^{14}$ and do any meaningful tests on them.

[image]

---

#### Edit

After the excellent comment by @GregHurst code like the one below from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85720/10397), could bring you down to a couple of weeks, without taking into account the time for your test. However, you may be limited by memory.

As pointed out by @Roman, we can know there are exactly `PrimePi[10^14]`$= 3204941750802$ prime numbers below $10^{14}$, and you better not try to have them all in memory (46 TB).

```
PrimesUpTo = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
  Block[{S = Range[2, n]},
    Do[
      If[S[[i]] != 0,
        Do[
          S[[k]] = 0,
          {k, 2i+1, n-1, i+1}
        ]
      ],
      {i, Sqrt[n]}
    ];
    Select[S, Positive]
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];
```

Comment: You can get the exact number of primes less than $10^{14}$ with `PrimePi[10^14]`, giving 3'204'941'750'802 (pretty close to your estimate of $n/\ln n$).

Answer (score 8):

[The prime generator](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NextPrime.html) and [the primality proving package](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PrimalityProving/tutorial/PrimalityProving.html) both seem very quick at $10^{14}$:

```
Needs["PrimalityProving`"]
ProvablePrimeQ[NextPrime[10^14]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {0.004102, True}    *)
```